# EJB - Lookup failed for 'ejb/BookRequestBean'

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3

I am new to EJB, and was trying "Hello World" type of EJB Java program. Here is my EJB:

```
package dukesbookstore.ejb;
@Stateless(name="BookRequestBean", mappedName="ejb/BookRequestBean")
@Named
public class BookRequestBean {
    //Other codes here
}
```

and here is my client:

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
    prop.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
    prop.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(prop);                              
        ctx.lookup("ejb/BookRequestBean");
        System.out.println("EJB Look-up successfull!!");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But whenever I try to run, I am getting below exception:

> javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'ejb/BookRequestBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=localhost, java

I have added `appserv-rt.jar` , `gf-client.jar`, `javaee.jar`, but still no luck. Can anyone help me, what I am missing here? I am usign Glassfish 3.1

Comment: Full stacktrace would help. Make sure you also look at this : http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#POJOLocalEJB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to nice @RaviTrivedi answer, here are few thoughts:

- `@Named` annotation shouldn't be used this way
- don't use both `name` and `mappedName`, for Glassfish it is enough to use just `mappedName`
- your EJB should implement remote interface

Comment: Slight interjection. `name` is used to identify EJB whereas `mappedName` is EJB's JNDI name. Also `mappedName` is vendor specific. ie: Glassfish supports, Websphere not.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi Yep, that's why I noted that it's enough for Glassfish. It shouldn't be used if you want fully portable applications.

Answer (score 8):

There can be several reasons to this:

**1)** Your `EJB` is not mapped to *JNDI* name. You need to check whether your `EJB` is deployed successfully and it is mapped to *JNDI* name. You can check `Server GUI`, `Server Log on startup` or use `Universal Test Client` to see if `EJB` is mapped correctly. Note, `UTC` will only show *Remotely exposed* EJBs.

**2)** Your `EJB` is only exposed to *Local* application. In this case, *Remote call* or *Cross application call*(different EAR, WAR...) to your `EJB` will fail. In this scenario, create *Remote interface* and expose it. *Local interface* exposes EJB to only local calls. *Remote interface* exposes EJB to *remote* or *cross application calls*.

**3)** Your `RMI/IIOP` *port* may be incorrect. You can check `Glassfish GUI` or `Server startup log` to see what *port* `RMI/IIOP` is assigned to.

**Note:** To diagnose the exact problem, please post full stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Ravi Trivedi and @Miljen Mikic, if you are using Glassfish, you should check how your EJB is registered in JNDI.  In Glassfish for example type the following command:

```
 asadmin list-jndi-entries
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> 1. your above code works perfectly on glassfish only missing was the remote interface.
> 2. As suggested above mappedname[vendor specific] and name ....yada yada.....
> 3. copy below code and run you should be good to go
> 4. only ensure the *client*.jar is on your path and redeploy the application to glassfish server and run main.
> ```

```
**This Remote interface (the only addition to your above code);**        
            import javax.ejb.Remote;
            
            @Remote
            public interface BookRequestI {
                //Other codes here
                String getISBN();
            }
            
            **your existing implementation spiced with my getISBN() to prove the point :)**
            
            import javax.ejb.Stateless;
            
            
            @Stateless(name="BookRequestBean", mappedName="ejb/BookRequestBean")
            public class BookRequest implements BookRequestI {
                //Other codes here
                @Override
                public String getISBN(){
                    return "ISBN 87 - 11 - 07559 - 7";
                }
            }
            
            **your test as is with my getISBN and typing to interface Type.**
            
            import javax.naming.Context;
            import javax.naming.InitialContext;
            import javax.naming.NamingException;
            import java.util.Properties;
            
            public class BookRequestT {
            
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                   Properties prop = new Properties();
                    prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
                    prop.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
                    prop.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
                    try {
            
                        Context ctx = new InitialContext(prop);
                        BookRequestI bookRequest = (BookRequestI) ctx.lookup("ejb/BookRequestBean");
                        System.out.println("EJB Look-up successfull!!" +  bookRequest.getISBN());
                    } catch (NamingException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            
                }
            }
            
            output:
            EJB Look-up successfull!!ISBN 87 - 11 - 07559 - 7
            
            Process finished with exit code 0
```